# Hashicorp vault how to list all roles

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is it possible to list all roles stored in a vault backend? I can't seem to find any reference on how to do so.

From the documentation, it seems possible to list a role given the role name, through `auth/approle/role/my-role`, for example, but I don't see any references on how to list *all* roles stored in a vault server.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**EDIT**

I would recommend viewing roles through the CLI. Viewing roles through the UI seems show *all* roles instead of those assigned to a given auth method.

**Viewing roles using the UI**

1. Click the "Access" tab

[image: access-tab]

2. Click "View Configuration" under the three dot dropdown for the auth method you're interested in

[image: view-config]

3. Click the "Roles" tab at the top

[image: roles]

**Viewing roles using the CLI**

Roles are listed under Authentication Methods in Vault. You can view which authentication methods you have enabled (or enable new ones) by visiting the UI and clicking on the "Access" tab at the top.

From there you can list roles using the following command:

```
vault list auth/{auth_method}/role
```

Where `{auth_method}` is one of the enabled authentication methods listed in the "Access" tab.

For example, if you enabled the `kubernetes` auth method, you would list roles associated with this method by running the following:

```
vault list auth/kubernetes/role
```

Comment: For me the GUI did not have the Roles Tab. However viewing roles using the CLI worked.

Comment: same i didnt see the roles in the tab and i am log as admin

Comment: both the UI and the CLI worked for me using vault v1.6.1

Comment: i have 1.6.0  will update and check, thanks.

Comment: i updated the version from 1.6.0 to 1.6.1  and cant see them in the UI but doing "vault list auth/approle/role"  does show my roles, the UI only show the configuration tab

Comment: No approles for me either. The command "vault list auth/approle/role" says "No value found at auth/approle/role". I am logged in with root token, and the approle auth method is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what auth method you created, based on auth method you can list roles.

Example:

```
# vault list auth/aws/role
# vault read auth/aws/role/role-name
```

Comment: vault read auth/aws/role/role-name

Comment: You need to add `s` at the end, `.../roles`. `vault list auth/token/roles` and `vault read auth/token/roles/my-cool-role`.

Answer (score 0):

On Vault v1.15.6 the role is not visible, but you can dig a bit deeper to see the default role assigned to the authentication method. For example:

*Access > Authentication Methods > click ... next to the method (in my case oidc) > click Configure (first line under "Configuration", a bit to the right) > look under Configuration tab (should be displayed by default)*

Now the second field down is called "Default Role" and in that field you can see the role currently assigned to the authentication method.
[image]